# impact of different Christian theologies on the psyche

Tags: ethics, free-will, society, christianity, moral-agency

I am afraid I do not have the expertise to form this question correctly, but I will give it a try: I want to understand how each of the different Christian theologies that exist (Evangelical Christians, Catholics, Orthodox, etc) impacts the psyche of its followers. Not the differences in rituals, dogma beliefs and the like (i.e. no religious jargon), but differences in mentality and personality that might be traced back to each specific Christian set of beliefs.

For example: Suppose we have three people who are not Christians, but grew up in families that are Christian. The first person grew up in an Evangelical Christian family, the second in a Catholic family, and the third in an Orthodox family (and so on). To these people, the words "born again", "mass/service", "church", "Holy Trinity", "savior", "prayer" etc do not really mean anything, they have never read the gospels, and they do not follow any religious practices at all, you get the idea.

What will be the difference in their character/mentality/worldview/choices/actions, considering the different religious environments they grew up in? For example what differences might one expect from them in the way they handle grief, shame, wrong-doing, good and evil, morality, ethics, judgement, punishment, ostracism, free will, love, and their life perspective in general?

My question (in part) stems from a conversation that I overheard about cancel culture: someone complained about it being very "black or white", with no space for (human) fault, and another person replied "Indeed, this evangelical 'in or out' resonates with me, and it is very hard to explain to people who have not lived through it". Any ideas on what the second person had in mind when making this comment?

And, in general, I would be grateful for any references I could look into for this (broad and ill-phrased) question.

Comment: " impacts the psyche"? "Not the differences in rituals, dogma beliefs and the like..." but different "Christian sects" are different social entities that share belief, rituals, and so on and **not** "theologies". There is a basic layer of social relations on top of which we have culture and only after that we have "ideologies": philosophy, theology, science.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is more a question on sociology or social psychology. It comes to my mind Max Weber's classic *[The Protestant Ethic and the Spirit of Capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Protestant_Ethic_and_the_Spirit_of_Capitalism#:%7E:text=In%20the%20book%2C%20Weber%20wrote,accumulation%20of%20wealth%20for%20investment.)*.

Comment: This [book](https://www.amazon.com/Dominion-Christian-Revolution-Remade-World/dp/1541675592/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1Z0R4SU41UV65&keywords=tom+holland+dominion&qid=1645262313&s=books&sprefix=tom+holland+domini%2Cstripbooks%2C175&sr=1-1) by Tom Holland might be also interesting.